# Populate class from textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to fill the class with data and use this data anywhere else on the program, where I will need it.

I created this class:

```
public class id
{
    
    private string name; // field
    
    public string Name // property
    {
        get { return name; } // get method
        set { name = value; } // set method
    }
}
```

And in `form_name` I tried to fill the class this way:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    id IDOBJE = new id();
    {
        IDOBJE.Name = txtshenimi.Text;
    }

    this.Close();
}
```

But I don't get any results. Could someone help me to clarify this?

What I have tried:

And in another form I tried to retrieve data like this:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    id idobje = new id();
    txtrez.Text = idobje.Name;
}
```

Comment: `new id();` creates a *new* object - it has no connection to the other object you created before. You need to store that object somewhere so you can retrieve its information

Comment: I think you're missing a lot of things here buddy. you want to create an Id object from another Form then return it to your current Form. If that's what you want then you should return the created object from that Form not recreating the object again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some `global` area to store and access a common variable.

For example, create a class as a central repository.

```
public static class Globals {
    public object myObj;
}
```

Then assign your created object to this one on first form.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    id IDOBJE = new id();
    {
        IDOBJE.Name = txtshenimi.Text;
    }
    Globals.myObj = IDOBJE;
    this.Close();
```

}

Access that on your second form this way.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    id idobje = (id)Globals.myObj;
    txtrez.Text = idobje.Name;
}
```